# Why do I see a screenshot of something that I was doing in the background on my smartphone?

Tags: huawei, malware

When I take a screenshot it does not appear on it, it is like seeing through a drawn glass, It can only be seen from the outside, it's hard to explain.

Is it some kind of malware? The screenshot looks much better when there is a solid color and it can be seen perfectly, it is as if the screenshot were on my screen.  I have already rebooted my device and it still continues.

Comment: The Huawei devices have a number of gestures to use to make screenshots general or highly specific. You will want to look at settings intrinsic to them, since you can capture menus and tabs on top of screens, so, multi-layered can be captured but not as you intended. Read your user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you see a little impression of the previous screen you were on even after you switch the app right? For example: You are using youtube and the you press home key and go to home screen but you can still see the faded view of the youtube app on homescreen.

First of all that's totally normal! I have a leeco le2 and experience the same thing everyday.. It's just because of the limitation of your screen(hardware). It's not any malware.. and definitely nothing to worry about.